# Reading String content in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following `String str;` being used to store *Hexadecimal* data.

```
str = bytesToHex(readData);
```

The content will look like

```
01030202BCB89500
```

How can I get only `02BC`?

Comment: `String out = str.substring(6,10);`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is a `String`, as in: `"01030202BCB89500"`, you can use the following:

```
String expectedVal = "01030202BCB89500".substring(startpoint,endpoint);
```

Answer (score -1):

`String.split` splits strings on a regular expression:

```
String[] strarray = str.split("");
readText.setText(strarray[7]+strarray[8]+strarray[9]+strarray[10]);
```

Comment: If you are going to access the string by index, why not use str.charAt(7) and so on ?

Comment: Are you answering your own question? It doesn't make sense that you asked the question 2 minutes back and answered it yourself..

Comment: Splitting the array and accessing individual characters doesn't really make much sense to me when other and better options are available: `String.substring`.  You also seem to be using some sort of Swing or widget to set the text.  In what context are you trying to use this code for?  I think you're also trying to answer your question.... a poor answer IMO, but I digress.

Comment: I just did a Q&A style question, not my intention to answer my own question, but to find a better solution than mine. ;)